# Simple todo app crashed on Heroku (local works fine)

Tags: node.js, heroku, vue.js

I downloaded following source, run it locally and works fine
https://vuejsexamples.com/weekly-todo-list-in-vue-js/

Uploading (via Github) works fine, however when I load the page it says Application error.

Heroku gives me the following error. I do not even know how to access the following log file. Any one knows?

> 2018-08-25T20:14:40.966872+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
>   /app/.npm/_logs/2018-08-25T20_14_40_957Z-debug.log
>   2018-08-25T20:14:41.322064+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
>   desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=xxx-app.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=aa2b7d48-198f-4fd1-b83e-70c92fc06ac6 fwd="84.82.96.205"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Comment: Have you run `npm run build` and set up basic `Express` server in your app main directory?

Comment: Doesn't Heroku do that for me?

Comment: You need to do some basic configuration: https://medium.com/netscape/deploying-a-vue-js-2-x-app-to-heroku-in-5-steps-tutorial-a69845ace489

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku requires that you set up an app server (HTTP server) to serve you static files. weekly-todo-vue doesn't do this.

I can offer 3 solutions: add a web server and change build process, extract the app build and deploy it separately with a server, use webpack-dev-server as your server on Heroku.

### Add a server and tweak the build process

Move build into **postinstall** script

```
// package.json
scripts: {
  // omited ...
  "postinstall": "yarn run build",
  // omitted...
},
```

Change **start** npm script

```
// package.json
scripts: {
  // omited ...
  "start": "node server.js",
  // omitted...
},
```

Some packages should be moved from **devDependencies** to **dependencies** since we going to build an app on Heroku and Heroku did this in the production environment.
This is quite tedious so you can move devDependencies into dependencies. But it will add unnecessary deps. into your build.

Install Express.JS dependency:

```
$ yarn add express
```

In the root of the repo create server.js file with the app server code that will serve the app static files:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port);
```

Commit all the changes and push it to Heroku

```
$ git push heroku master
```

### Extract build

Make build from the repo:

```
$ yarn run build
```

Create new repo and copy the `dist` directory. Don't forgot to add `node_modules/` into .gitignore.

Init new package.json:

```
$ npm init -y
```

Add start npm script;

```
// package.json
scripts: {
  "start": "node server.js",
  // omitted...
},
```

Install Express.JS dependency:

```
$ yarn add express
```

In the root of the repo create server.js file with the app server code that will serve the app static files, same server as in previous solution:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port);
```

You should have the project structure like this:

```
.
├── dist
│   ├── index.html
│   └── static
│       ├── css
│       │   ├── app.c0fc4ae18c0c95b09c1cb7ceb99d491f.css
│       │   └── app.c0fc4ae18c0c95b09c1cb7ceb99d491f.css.map
│       ├── fonts
│       │   ├── icons.674f50d.eot
│       │   ├── icons.af7ae50.woff2
│       │   ├── icons.b06871f.ttf
│       │   └── icons.fee66e7.woff
│       ├── img
│       │   ├── flags.9c74e17.png
│       │   └── icons.912ec66.svg
│       └── js
│           ├── app.88670f817a4b11e940e6.js
│           ├── app.88670f817a4b11e940e6.js.map
│           ├── manifest.304e67c5c14ed63ee160.js
│           ├── manifest.304e67c5c14ed63ee160.js.map
│           ├── vendor.434b5723496264d2da17.js
│           └── vendor.434b5723496264d2da17.js.mapo
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
└── server.js
```

Commit the code and push it to Heroku.

### Use webpack-dev-server

As stated [here](https://help.heroku.com/P1AVPANS/why-is-my-node-js-app-crashing-with-an-r10-error) you can use **webpack-dev-server** to serve your app. But this is highly not recommended for production applications.

Add webpack dev server config to webpack.prod.conf.js:

```
     // ..omitted
     devtool: config.build.productionSourceMap ? config.build.devtool : false,
  +  devServer: {
  +    disableHostCheck: true,
  +    clientLogLevel: 'warning',
  +    historyApiFallback: true,
  +    hot: false,
  +    host: '0.0.0.0',
  +    port: process.env.PORT || config.dev.port,
  +    open: false,
  +    overlay: false,
  +    publicPath: config.dev.assetsPublicPath,
  +    proxy: config.dev.proxyTable,
  +    quiet: true // necessary for FriendlyErrorsPlugin
  +  },
     output: {
     // ..omitted
```

Change start npm script:

```
// package.json
scripts: {
  // omited ...
  "start": "webpack-dev-server --port $PORT --host 0.0.0.0 --config build/webpack.prod.conf.js",
  // omitted...
},
```

Some packages should be moved from **devDependencies** to **dependencies** since we going to build an app on Heroku and Heroku did this in the production environment.
This is quite tedious so you can move devDependencies into dependencies. But it will add unnecessary deps. into your build.

Commit the change and push to Heroku.

### Node/npm version issue with Heroku

Heroku loves strict engine specs in package.json. I would recommend that you specify explicit versions of Node.JS and NPM:

```
   "engines": {
-    "node": ">= 8.0.0",
-    "npm": ">= 5.0.0"
+    "node": "8.11.4",
+    "npm": "5.6.0"
   },
```

Comment: Wow great answer!

I executed "Add a server and tweak the build process" and that of course did the trick. My app is up and running now. Awesome!

Thanks @shvetsovdm

Comment: @RichardDuinmayer thanks for the feedback. I'm glad that the answer helped you.